# c# how to post request with form data using System.net.http

Tags: c#, http, post

Hi I'm wondering how to post request to a url that accepts form data using System.net.http.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", addID[1]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("qtd", addID[2]),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("commit", "add")
};
HttpContent formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pData);
MultipartFormDataContent postData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
postData.Add(formData);
var postResponse = client.PostAsync(site + "/add", postData);
```

Comment: duplicate,  go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)